# Ruby Sequel memory leak?

Tags: ruby, memory-leaks, sequel

I need to read many SQLite databases, over 54,000 databases, to generate statistics.

I created a Ruby application, running on Ruby 1.8.7 patchlevel 371, using Sequel 3.44.0 and Sqlite 1.3.7.

I wrote this code to read databases:

```
for i in databases 
   db= Sequel.sqlite(i)
        # DB'query and other operation
   db.disconnect
end
```

After a while the program crashes with no errors. I looked at the memory's consumption while my application runs, and it increases until size of RAM.

Is it a garbage collection problem? Or do I have any mistakes? Are there any methods for reading a lot of databases with Ruby?

---

Edit:

I have 4GB RAM. I tried with:

```
databases.each { |i| }
```

but nothing worked. When the program reaches 2GB of memory use it stopped.

Comment: Might be a scoping problem. Try `databases.each {|i| ... }`. No one uses the `for` loop anyway.

Comment: `for i in` is not a Ruby specific way for array iteration. You should try `each` or other block methods instead.

Comment: What do you do inside the loop? Do you collect data of all DB to a central data storage? You wrote: `crashes with no error`. What's the last info on the screen? Or do you start your script with double click and the sreen disappears - then start your application from a shell to see the last message.

Comment: Although @Tass’s suggestion seems to be reasonable, another question is what amount of RAM do you have? Is it possible that for instance you perform kinda `load_all_content_in_memory.do_calc()` operation and, say, n-th database does not simply fit in memory?

Comment: I have 4 Gb on my pc... and 24Gb on server but when program reaches 2Gb,it crashes

Comment: 2GB is the maximum available to Ruby when compiled for 32-bit if I remember right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sequel caches databases you connect to in the `Sequel::DATABASES` array.  If you connect/disconnect from a large number of databases you should remove your database objects from the `Sequel::DATABASES` array so that they can be garbage collected.

http://sequel.rubyforge.org/rdoc/classes/Sequel.html

Answer (score 0):

If you have 54,000 SQLite database, I think it's time for you to step up to a more capable DBM that can contain the data of those individual files. That will instantly fix the problem of running out of RAM due to opening so many separate database. I'll recommend PostgreSQL, but MySQL is easily up to the task too.

Even if you must have 54,000 separate tables, you can connect to the server using a single `Sequel.connect` and iterate over the tables using the `DB.tables` method, conserving memory.

Another advantage to doing this is you can correlate data across the different tables for your statistics easily.